# Edit an existing file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I have preferences file for my application in Qt.
Whenever I launch the application it loads the file & depending the contents creates the widgets accordingly. I have given some customisation option for the user. Now when my application is closed I am checking whether the preferences are changed. If yes then I am opening the preferences file again & then just adding everything again in it. I am not creating a temporary file, I am directly editing the file. Is this method an efficient one? or am I doing it wrong? because I found these threads:
1. [What is the best way to edit the middle of an existing flat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732469/what-is-the-best-way-to-edit-the-middle-of-an-existing-flat-file)

2. http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25924/

Should use I binary file? Currently I am using ASCII file.
Thanks.

UPDATE: In the stackoverflow link above the correct answer has

> If you're stuck using flat, then you're stuck using the old fashioned
>   way of updating them

I meant to ask whether the method I am using is old fashioned & is there a better method used nowadays? & what does flat file mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't try to edit the file. Rewrite the whole thing
2. Rewrite by using a temporary file. i.e. write the current state of preferences into temp file. And then move/rename the file to your actual preference file after making sure the temp file has been written successfully. This helps in case there is a crash when you rewriting the file. If you rewrite it directly, you will be left with neither the old one nor a good new one. In case you do it through a temp file, then do it this way ensures that in case of a crash, you atleast have a good preferences file(though it contains the old preferences).
3. Text/Binary doesn't make much difference unless it's a really huge file. Text will help to hand edit it if required.

Comment: More or less obvious, but... Don't forget to ensure that the newly written file was successfully written before erasing the old file and renaming the new one.  (Just check the status _after_ the close.)

Comment: Don't delete the old file as software tracking the file will get a worng deletion/new notification instead of a change one. Copy old file somewhere and then write over the existing one.

Comment: @RedX What software tracking the file.  I've always used deletion, then move, and the only time I've had any problems was when there were several hard links to the file.  (But that was long ago.  No one uses hard links any more.)

Comment: For instance C# or windows FileChangeNotification might fail. (There was no mention of an OS)

Comment: @RedX So?  Who uses them, and for what?  (As I said, I've done this a lot, both under Unix and under Windows, and I've never had it cause a problem.)

Comment: I had a problem with vim and css files. Vim creates per default a copy of the old file, deletes it and then writes a new one. A software that i used to watch for css files did not like this behaviour. (I just wanted to point this out, there is no need to continue the discussion)

Comment: Can anybody please tell me what "flat" file is?
& what is he reffering to "old fashioned" in that answer in 1st link?

Comment: @Cool_Coder - In very simple terms, a flat file is a file which your program knows how to read, in contrast to a database which your program may not be able to read directly without using the Database's APIs/SQL etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfectly fine way of doing it. Since you already seem to have all of the preferences loaded into memory and you have edited them there, you don't need to bother with a temporary file (unless you want to ensure safety if your program fails during writing). Just write all of the preferences back into the original file.

Whether you choose a binary file or text file is up to you. Preferences tend to be text files because they have the added benefit of being human readable with just a text editor, rather than some specialised software for viewing them. A binary file may, however, have slightly better performance due to simpler decoding.

Comment: You still need the temporary file, because otherwise, you can easily loose your data.

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree. I meant that they don't need a temporary file in the same way as the linked answer suggests as that's just because they're parsing the file at the same time as writing it.